# Need to automate file transfer from linux server to windows shared folder

Tags: linux, ssh, mount

We need to transfer files from a Linux server to a Windows shared folder. we don't have any Samba server. Can you please explain a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mount a windows network share via the `mount` command:

```
mount -t cifs //server/share /mnt/ -o username=user
```

- `server` can be the ip or the hostname of the windows server.
- `share` is the name of the network share
- `/mnt/` is the mountpoint in the local linux machine
- `user` is the username that has the needed privileges
- you will be prompted for the password

After mounting just copy the file:

```
cp /path/to/file /mnt/wherever
```